# powershell scheduled task always shows running even once completed

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

I have a PowerShell script set to run daily as a scheduled task, it is setup with an action of:
Run Program
PowerShell.exe
Arguments: -executionpolicy bypass -file D:\Scripts\SomeScript.ps1

The script completes successfully and in task manager I can see PowerShell start then close, but Task Scheduler still shows it Running.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though the script was doing everything it was configured to it seems I needed to place all of the arguments inside quotes.

Old arguments (everything completed fine but task hung):
-executionpolicy bypass -file 'D:\Scripts\SomeScript.ps1'

New arguments (everything still completes fine including the Task):
"-executionpolicy bypass -file 'D:\Scripts\SomeScripts.ps1'"

Not sure why this one server is requiring quotes, I run this exact script on multiple servers running the save version of Windows and same version of PowerShell, NONE of them have the quotes, but it works.

Answer (score 11):

Just a tiny note: If you run a task manually it will go to "running" in task scheduler library.  Wait until your task finishes and then hit F5 to refresh.

Comment: OMG that works - but isn't it ridiculous that you have to do this?!

Comment: You save my day. I've spent whole day trying to figure out what's wrong with my schedule or powershell. Ended up I just need a F5